# strip query string after page load

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im developing php and my webpage urls are like this

```
http://localhost/myweb/?action=news
http://localhost/myweb/?action=my_profile
http://localhost/myweb/?action=my_upload
http://localhost/myweb/?action=my_collection
http://localhost/myweb/?action=chat
http://localhost/myweb/?action=my_friends
etc
```

and for example, in particular page there's delete feature that access a href link

```
http://localhost/myweb/?action=my_friends&delete=2414535435 <-friends id
```

i do this to make it tidy by making the link cant be seen without looking at the source

```
a href='#'
```

and using javascript to access the real link

```
$('.deleteclass').on('click', function () {
        var name= $(this).attr('nameattr');
        if(confirm('You sure want to delete '+name+'?')){
            window.location='?action=my_friends&delete='+this.id;
        }
    });
```

the problem is, after i process the delete and load the page, i don't want the full link on the address bar.

```
http://localhost/myweb/?action=my_friends&delete=2414535435
```

i need to make it back look like this on the address bar

```
http://localhost/myweb/?action=my_friends
```

is it possible? through mod rewrite perhaps?

Comment: Don't use this kind of obfuscation to give yourself a false sense of security.  It will be very easy for anyone to figure out the required URL to delete.  You need to make sure you have extra checks in your php code.

Comment: yes i noticed, and i've put some more requirements in php if the person can execute the code or not. actualy it's okay for me if the person figured the link, but somehow i don't want it to show on the address bar.

Comment: And i use link because i don't know how to do it with button (submit), because in my case each table row has a delete link, not a single delete button for all/chosen one.

Comment: You need each row to be a seperate form or each delete submit button to include the id of the item you wish to delete.  Probably best ot have a form per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not strip a url after the browser has loaded the page.

Just do a redirect after your delete or other action.

```
header('Location: /myweb/?action=my_friends');
```

Add error/success messages to a session variable (in the action script before doing the header) so you can show them on the other page

```
$_SESSION['errors'] = "Delete Failed: For Some Reason";
```

And on the other pages check to see if the session variable exists, show it and then remove it (otherwise it will stay there and the pages will continue to think there was an error)

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
   //Do some code to show the error
   ...
   unset($_SESSION['errors']); //delete the error messages
}
```

Comment: thanks for your clarification, this is what i do now, but it makes some data i needed gone. such as error message if the delete failed.

Comment: If there is an error save the error into a session variable and look for errors in the session variable on the other pages. updated answer showing the session code